# Odoo:why the location is not the same on the reception?

Tags: location, odoo, stock

when we receive product we choose the destination location on the warehouse

why the location_dest_id on the stock_move is not the same selected  ?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your issue in my system. Generally when we select Destination Location on Purchase Order, it will send that value into Destination Location.

I think, this issue will come because of custom module.

You need to track *_prepare_order_line_move* method. Checkout which value pass in *location_dest_id*

Comment: it's not on the _prepare_order_line_move

Comment: if you just create an picking_in and set the location destination on the process of reception
location_dest_id not change just on the stock.pack.operation

Comment: if we create a picking line with different destination location than it will raise warning at time of Transfer. Warning message is that *The destination location must be the same for all the moves of the picking.* Without making same destination location you may not transfer quantity of product.